# Need To Disable A Table When A Link Clicked

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 3 table which contains links.  What i'm after is to disable the table when one of the links are click and also for the table to give the user a visual that the table is disabled (e.g. turn to a light transparent gray color and make the other links none underline when hovered over.

The code below is how my table is populated

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped hidden-xs" id="clientListTable">
                <tr><%
                foreach (var cell in data.Header.Cells)
                {
                    var showFilterOption = (cell.DisplayType == AJBG.Web.Services.Entities.Enums.ColumnDisplayType.Currency || cell.DisplayType == AJBG.Web.Services.Entities.Enums.ColumnDisplayType.Double || cell.DisplayType == AJBG.Web.Services.Entities.Enums.ColumnDisplayType.Integer);
                    var filterIcon = ResolveUrl("~/Resources/Images/Interface/filter_icon.png");
                    var sortDirection = AJBG.Web.Services.Entities.Enums.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending.ToString();
                    if (data.ColumnSort == cell.SortOn && data.ColumnSortDirection == AJBG.Web.Services.Entities.Enums.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending)
                    {
                        sortDirection = AJBG.Web.Services.Entities.Enums.ColumnSortOrder.Descending.ToString();
                    }
                    %>
                    <th>
                        <a href="<%=Html.GenerateLoopBackUrl(true, new { ClientList_SortOn = cell.SortOn, ClientList_SortDirection = sortDirection })%>"><%=cell.Value%></a>
                        <%if (showFilterOption)
                            { %> 
                                <a href="#" id="<%:cell.ColumnIdentifier%>_link" class="noPdf">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" id="<%:cell.ColumnIdentifier%>_img"></span>
                                </a>
                                <%--<img src="<%= filterIcon%>" alt="add filter" id="<%:cell.ColumnIdentifier%>_img" />--%>
                        <%}%>
                    </th>
                <% }%> 
                </tr>

                <%Int32 count = 0;
                    foreach (var row in data.Rows)
                    { %>
                    <tr>
                        <%
                            foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
                            {
                                    if (cell.Hidden) { }
                                    else {%><td onclick="return clickDisableFunction();"><%=cell.Value%></td><%}
                            }
                        %>
                    </tr>
                    <%
                    count++;
                    } 
                    if (data.ShowTotal)
                    { %>
                    <tr>
                        <%
                            foreach (var cell in data.Total.Cells)
                            { 
                                %><td><strong><%=cell.Value%></strong></td><%
                            }
                        %>
                    </tr>
                <% }%>
                </table>
```

The below Java is what I have tried and it appears to work

```
    function RedirectClientView()
{
    //document.location.href = $('Views_DropDownList').value;
    document.location.href = document.getElementById('Views_DropDownList').value;
}
var clickedOnce = false;

function clickDisableFunction()
{
    if (clickedOnce == true)
    {
        return false;
    };
    clickedOnce = true;
    document.getElementById('clientListTable').setAttribute("disabled","true")
};
```

But although this disables the links in the table, it does not give the user the impression the table is disabled.

As I said I want it to display some sort of transparent gray box over the table.  How do I achieve this using css and/or jquery

Comment: Did you tried `fadeIn` effect on table ?

Comment: @TusharRaj, wont this just remove the table completely though?

Comment: i have edited my code ...you were right ..it would `fadeOut` the table completely .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use the modal which works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.table-inactive {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

javascript:

```
var table = document.getElementById("clientListTable")
    table.className = table.className + " table-inactive";
```

or jQuery:

```
var $table = $("#clientListTable");
    $table.addClass("table-inactive");
```

That should do it, it doesn't cover the table, but it will appear faded out with the opacity.
*(place the CSS/JS where you need/want it)*

Answer (score 0):

Try this . I am writing a generic solution . Hope this may help :-

**`Lets say your bootstrap table contains 3 links`**

**First Solution :** `modal-backdrop in`

I guess you are having `bootstrap.css` in your application . Keeping that in mind :-
There is a class that `bootstrap3` provides **modal-backdrop  in** . Add a div containing this class before your `<table>` like this :-

```
$("#lnk1,#lnk2,#lnk3").on("click",function(){

     $("#tableId").before("<div class='modal-backdrop  in'></div>");

 });
```

I have a personal experience with this feature .

**Second Solution :** `Opacity`

```
 $("#lnk1,#lnk2,#lnk3").on("click",function(){

     $("#tableId").css({'opacity':'0.4'});

 });
```

Hope this would help you .

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

```
function clickDisableFunction()
{
    if (clickedOnce == true)
    {
        return false;
    };
    clickedOnce = true;
    $("#clientListTable").css( "opacity":"0.6" );
    document.getElementById('clientListTable').setAttribute("disabled","true")

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Drop the opacity of the table to the half and then make the colors of link text to some light like grey so that it could give the feel like disabled.